# how to Create Angular 4 project instead of angular 5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

How To create angular 4 project ,cause when I user ng new new-project it will automatically create angular 5 but I need angular 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade to the older Angular CLI (1.4.9). The most recent version (1.5.0) will only create Angular 5 projects.

Comment: I tried to run "npm install -g angular-cli@1.4.9" but I get error "no matching version foundd for angular-cli@1.49"

Comment: Hey Adir, Try using this command: npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9